# Django: TokenAuthentication and AbstractBaseUser Errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django 1.8.4 and Django rest framework 3.2.3. Because I want override "username" field I had to use "AbstractBaseUser"
The used model is:

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.EmailField(max_length=75, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    tel_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    user_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_avatar', blank=True, null=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['tel_number']
```

Now I want create new user with new token:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    data = {}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.save()
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        data['token'] = token
        data = serializer.data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and my serializer is :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Users
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'tel_number', 'address', 'user_image')
```

But I get this error on "Create Token Lines":

```
Cannot query "a@gmail.com": Must be "User" instance.
```

Comment: Please show your serializer.

Comment: i adding serializer, please help me

Comment: You are using abstract user model what did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the user instance to Token. 
Can you try this:

In routers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .viewsets import UserSeralizerViewSets
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserSeralizerViewSets)
```

In urls.py

```
from .routers import router
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

In viewsets.py

```
class UserSeralizerViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSeralizer
    queryset = Users.objects.all()

   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       data = {}
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       user = serializer.save()
       token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
       data['token'] = token.key
       return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of **seenu s** is well but i use this line in settings.py and worked .

```
     AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Users'
```

Users.Users is (myappname.mymodelname)
I find this on Django doc.